# Communication with the server side is not working - node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I'm kind of new using node.js. I'm using express with jQuery and mySQL. 
I'm trying to add a record in to the db by filling 2 fields in the UI and then call a server via getJSON to add the record. I'm giving the details into the url. 
This is not working.

Here is a snippet from the code (I adjust it and eliminate all the checks to make it short)

**client side**

```
$("#btnAddEvent").click( function() {
  // Send details to the server to add a record to the db 
   var url2Send = '/insert/title/' + $("#Title").val() + '/desc/' + 
                  $("#Desc").val()
  $.getJSON( url2Send, function( data ) {
      $("#Title").empty();
       $("#Desc").empty();
    });
  });
}
```

**Server side**

```
router.get('/insert/title/:t/desc/:d', function(req, res) {
    var qry = "insert into events (evt_title, evt_desc) " + 
         "values (\'" + req.params.t + "\',\'" + req.params.d + "\')";

    app.connection.query( qry, function(err, qry_res) {
        if (err) {
            console.log( 'Error: ' + err );
            return false;
        }
        else { 
            console.log( 'Event added .....' );
            res.json(dd);
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

When I run and try to go through this code, it doesn't succeed and display the homepage instead. In the server console it shows it's trying to get the following

`GET /?add_event_title=lkjhkjhkj&add_event_desc=kjhkjhkj 200 306.584 ms - 19709`

`add_event_title` and `add_event_desc` are the IDs of the UI fields in the form used to define the db fields `evt_title` and `evt_desc` respectively. 
Any explanation for this please? Any way to make the communication smooth? 
Thanks

Comment: What is `dd` in `res.json(dd);`?

Comment: It's just a value I set before I send the query to the db. var dd = req.params.d; I forget to keep it when I posted the question

Comment: In the server script, if an error occurs, try ending the connection with a res.write("something"); just to see if it's a problem of letting the connection open without a response

Comment: It doesn't go through that piece of code (server code) at all. I had a console.log there to see if something will get out to the console but I didn't see anything.

Comment: This looks like you javascript is not even being called. Try changing `$("#btnAddEvent").click( function() {` to `$("#btnAddEvent").click( function(evt) { evt.preventDefault();`